# HAProxy Multiple port mapping - forwarding request to same port as incoming request on same backend servers

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I am fairly new to haproxy setup. I was able to successfully setup to route frontend requests to specific port on backend. But now I have got a request to route requests to same server but different ports. The backend port to where the request needs to be routed is same as the incoming port.  I tried below config among many options but nothing seems to work

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m

frontend  haproxynode_https
    bind 0.0.0.0:6443
    bind 0.0.0.0:10111
    bind 0.0.0.0:10121
    bind 0.0.0.0:10131
    bind 0.0.0.0:10141
    bind 0.0.0.0:10181
    bind 0.0.0.0:10191
    bind 0.0.0.0:10011
    bind 0.0.0.0:10021
    bind 0.0.0.0:10041
    bind 0.0.0.0:10051
    bind 0.0.0.0:10061
    bind 0.0.0.0:10071
    bind 0.0.0.0:10091
    bind 0.0.0.0:10241
    mode tcp     
    option tcplog
    timeout client 1h
    default_backend backendnodes_https

backend backendnodes_https
    mode tcp
    timeout server 1h
    option tcplog
    option tcp-check
    balance roundrobin
    default-server inter 10s downinter 5s rise 2 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 250 maxqueue 256 weight 100    
    server master XX.XXX.XX.XX weight 1 port 80 maxconn 512 check
    server master-1 XX.XXX.XX.XXX weight 1 port 80 maxconn 512 check
    server master-2 XX.XXX.XX.XX weight 1 port 80 maxconn 512 check
```

Any pointers is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

run first

`haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c`

Is all ok with the conf file ?

add at the end :

```
  listen stats
  bind  :20000
  mode  http
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats hide-version
  stats refresh 60
  stats realm Haproxy-Statistics
  stats auth admin:password
  stats admin if TRUE
```

Check the stats page : connect with a browser to

`http://ip:20000/stats`

send more info please